# What are three possible ways to express the following Boolean function with eight or fewer literals?

Tags: boolean-algebra

F= A'BC'D + AB'CD + A'B'C' + ACD'

I assumed that the question was asking for me to simplify. I placed the terms into a kmap and have gotten SOP F= A'B'C' + A'C'D + AB'C + ACD' or POS F= (A+C')(A'+C)(B'+C'+D')(A+B'+D). Neither of which are eight or less literals. For the POS I did minimize the (A+C')(A'+C) to (AxorC)' but am not sure if that would satisfy at least one way to express  the function. Thanks for any assistance.